Visual Studio 2022 with PowerShell Tools does not show anything on locals, why?
Using Win10 + Visual Studio (updated as of today) + Powershell Tools
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.12.3

Debugging and running the program works fine, but the LOCALS window is completely empty. I did run VS 2022 also as Administrator, no help.
Any idea what it could be?


